# Customizing the header with fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, fancyhdr

I am writing a report using the `scrreprt` KOMA class. Currently my header looks like this:

[image: Current header]

`Introduction` is the chapter name.

I would like to make two changes to it:

1. I would like to have the chapter name on the left of the header and the section name on the right. I have already tried `\lhead{\thechapter}` but this only gives me the chapter number, not the title.
2. How can I change the font used in the header to match the one in the figure? It looks like it's the default font for section titles in the KOMA classes, but I'm not 100% sure.
   [image: New header font]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redefine `\chaptermark`/ `\sectionmark` to display sectioning number plus title, and redefine `\lhead`/`\rhead` to use `\leftmark`/`\rightmark` plus the formatting instructions `\sffamily\bfseries`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.~~#1}{}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.~~#1}}

\lhead{\sffamily\bfseries \leftmark}
\rhead{\sffamily\bfseries \rightmark}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\section{foobar}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}​
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! However I have a couple of questions about your code: 1) what is the difference between `\markboth` and `\markright`? 2) What is the meaning of `\leftmark` and `\rightmark`?

Comment: @user1301428 See section 9 of the `fancyhdr` manual for a good explanation.